# Get list of views with adb command

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to understand the internals of an android application that has been handed to me and I am wondering if there is a quick way to identify the list of views the app may navigate to.

From what I understand, typically if one uses the command:

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "my_app://my_view"
```

Then you will be navigated to the `my_view` view in the application, but what I am after is a list of all such possible views I could navigate to.

Is there a method to figure this out from the source code perhaps? Or are there any typical guidelines/best-practices android developers follow when defining views that might help me get to what I require?

Comment: "From what I understand, typically if one uses the command" -- that command will work on few apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare
Thank you - In which case what commands are used?

Comment: From outside the app, you cannot force the app to go to any particular screen via a simple `adb` command, unless the developers of the app specifically set things up that way. Few developers will do that, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)'s `dump` to dump the tree of Views.

```
dump --help
usage: dump [OPTION]... [serialno]

Options:
  -H, --help                       prints this help
  -V, --verbose                    verbose comments
  -v, --version
  -I, --ignore-secure-device       ignore secure device
  -E, --ignore-version-check       ignores ADB version check
  -F, --force-view-server-use      force view server use (even if UiAutomator present)
  -S, --do-not-start-view-server   don't start ViewServer
  -k, --do-not-ignore-uiautomator-killed don't ignore UiAutomator killed
  -w, --window=WINDOW              dump WINDOW content (default: -1, all windows)
  -a, --all                        dump all information about Views
  -i, --uniqueId                   dump View unique IDs
  -x, --position                   dump View positions
  -b, --bounds                     dump View bounds
  -d, --content-description        dump View content descriptions
  -g, --tag                        dump View tags
  -c, --center                     dump View centers
  -f, --save-screenshot=FILE       save screenshot to file
  -W, --save-view-screenshots=DIR  save View screenshots to files in directory
  -D, --do-not-dump-views          don't dump views, only useful if you specified -f or -W
  -A, --device-art=MODEL           device art model to frame screenshot (auto: autodetected)
  -Z, --drop-shadow                drop shadow for device art screenshot
  -B, --glare                      screen glare over screenshot
  -h, --use-uiautomator-helper     use UiAutomatorHelper Android app
  -X, --debug=LIST                 debug options
```

Comment: Thank you Diego, for the suggestion. `dump` returns a list of views, where each line looks like `android.widget.TextView com.my_app.some_string:id/some_more_string`. I was expecting to be able to use the `adb` command in the question above with `my_app://id/some_more_string` as the intended navigation destination, but instead an `Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent` error is returned, so the output from `dump` does not to seem be what I need.

Comment: This is because the **Intent** is not valid, has nothing to do with the `View`s dumped